# Who is the Charadim Commentary on Jerusalem Talmud

Tags: halacha, history, talmud-gemara, torah-study, yerushalayim-jerusalem

Who is the author of this commentary?

[image: Charadim Commentary]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elazar_ben_Moshe_Azikri